# Inkscape - round several rectangles with the same radiums

Tags: inkscape

I have a bunch of rectangles, different sizes. How can I make them all have rounded corners with the same radius easily? I've tried copying one and stretching, but the rounding is stretched also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select all of your rectangles
- Choose the rectangle tool
- In the toolbar that has just changed or appeared, respectively, manually enter your desired value for *Rx* and *Ry.*

Answer (score 2):

By default stretching affects the corner rounding in proportion. However you can de-select the second icon in the "Affect:" part of the "Tool controls" bar, this will allow you to keep the size of corners while stretching objects.

[image: snapshot of toolbar]

So if you have not created the rectangles yet, you can copy the original one and then stretch it to the desired size without affecting the corners.

*Remark:* It is advisable that you also de-select the first icon in "Affect:", else the stroke thickness will be affected, which is probably not what you want.